# Debug android through adb without allow it

Tags: android, adb, android-source, custom-rom

I have sucessfully build the last oreo relase for my device but it reboot just after passed the boot process so I need to view the logcat for find the cause of the problem but I cant allow adb. Is possible to view the logcat through adb without allow it.

Comment: For an early crash you may want to get serial console output rather than ADB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- No, need to allow it in order to ENABLE it. If it's not ENABLED, it will not respond to any request.
- Other option is to have ADB enabled in your FW by default. For this, you could give these a try. Set them to this values in an MK file.

  `ro.secure=0 
  ro.adb.secure=0 
  ro.debuggable=1`
- Compile a userdebug kind of build, flash that (it has ADB enabled by default) and logcat the output.

Comment: I know that I can use ro.adb.secure=0 and ro.secure=0 for obtain a  Similar effect, is right?

Comment: Has it been helpful?